# Is my regEx correct?

Tags: java, regex

I have written a regEx in java for:

1. Expression should start with a `letter`.
2. Followed by `letter` or `number` or `period` or `@`
3. Ends with `abc.com` or `xyz.com`

Regex i tried:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9@\.]*?[abcxyz]\.com$
```

I think there is some problem in the 3rd condition. Can somebody please correct me or provide me a better regEx. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9@\.]*?` This part looks fishy. Are you trying to match an email address?

Comment: Are you trying to validate an email adress? Don't. Look here for a regex which catches most of valid adresses: http://stackoverflow.com/a/719543/1436981

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to escape the dot inside the character class and also put `abc` and `xyz` inside a  capturing or non-capturing group with `|` (*Logical OR operator*) as seperator.

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9@.]*?(?:abc|xyz)\.com$
```

Java regex would be,

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9@.]*?(?:abc|xyz)\\.com$
```

`[abcxyz]` in your regex matches a single character from the given list. That is , it would match `a` or `b` or `c` or `x` or `y` or `z`

Answer (score 3):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9@.]*?(?:\babc\b|\bxyz\b)\\.com$
```

Try this.`[abcxyz]` will match just 1 character like `a`,`b`, etc.

Comment: @TheLostMind just used OP's regex.Will correct it thanx.

Comment: @anubhava guess you should not have deleted your answer...u missed some brownie points :P

Comment: No I always delete my answer if I find it is duplicate of an already posted answer and upvote the existing answer. And almost everyday I crossover daily rep limit anyway so couple of upvotes won't matter much anyway :)

Comment: @anubhava dats something to look forward to :)

Answer (score 1):

May be I'm wrong but I guess you want to match an email address, so it's better to put the `@` outside the character class to be sure there is only one:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.]*@[A-Za-z0-9.]*(abc|xyz)\\.com$
```

But a regex that matches email address is much more complex, see [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9@.]*?(abc|xyz)\\.com$
```

Comment: Thanks for adding \, didn't see java tag, so I used simple regexp notation:) Big thanks:)